# Binary file proplem with jTableModel

Tags: java

i am writing in binary file objects by gui and when i list them in table only one line appears [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xesns.png)
not all data appers
and here is the code to list

```
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    Object rowData[] = new Object[5];
    model.setRowCount(0);
    Apparels a = new Apparels();
    ArrayList<Apparels> app = new ArrayList<Apparels>();

    app = a.listApparels();

    for (Apparels x : app) {
        rowData[0] = x.getStockid();
        rowData[1] = x.getPricePerItem();
        rowData[2] = x.getQuantity();
        rowData[3] = x.getType();
        rowData[4] = x.getCateogryname();

        model.addRow(rowData);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're re-using `rowData` to fill the properties, which means that for each row, it will have the same data

Maybe try using something more like...

```
for (Apparels x : app) {
    Object rowData[] = new Object[5];
    rowData[0] = x.getStockid();
    rowData[1] = x.getPricePerItem();
    rowData[2] = x.getQuantity();
    rowData[3] = x.getType();
    rowData[4] = x.getCateogryname();

    model.addRow(rowData);

}
```

The primary issue is, the reference to `rowData` never changes, but the content in each element does, so once you've finished looping the, model will have a list of references all pointing to the same instance of `rowData`